# Insulating basement foundation walls with partial interior walls

Tags: insulation, basement-refinishing, basement-insulation

A previous owner seemed to have fun with the basement (although I'm guessing at the order): the basement had previously been finished by building framing just inside the foundation walls and then hanging drywall.  They then realized that there were water intrusion issues and had a french drain installed, which means that the contractors removed the bottom ~3 feet of the interior walls.  The owners never bothered re-finishing the walls, presumably because the french drains didn't actually stop the water intrusion.

Fast forward a while, and I now have the water intrusion under control (it was mostly an issue with clogged drains connected to basement window wells) and am planning to start re-finishing the basement.  The thing is, when the person who finished the basement didn't bother with any insulation/vapor barrier on the foundation wall.  I'd like to at least get some insulation up if I can, and it would be nice to do this without having to tear out **all** of the current drywall (which is in good shape for the top ~5 feet of wall where it was left untouched).  My hope is to just replace the missing drywall, which is about three feet from the floor.  It *seems* like it should be possible to get some foam slabs on the wall without having to tear everything down.  I'm more dubious about installing a vapor barrier properly without a full tear out, but I've never had any trouble with condensation on the walls.

I live in Indiana, so insulation is my main concern.

I'm wondering if anyone has tried anything like this, has any suggestions on how to make it happen, or reasons why it just isn't possible?

Picture (you can see that someone started filling the bottom three feet with wood, but my plan is to just rip this out and put in drywall).

[image]

Comment: Too bad for most basements the top 4 or 5 feet give the greatest cost benefit for insulation.  Not saying it cannot be done but it usually is PITA to do right.  Vapour barrier probably more important with insulation on the walls instead of air flow.

Comment: @crip659 I'm guessing the top is the most important because it's less buried?

There is one wall in one room where I will likely tear out drywall.  The top foot or two of the walls are above ground, and the water pipes run on top of the foundation wall (with no real insulation around them).  They didn't freeze when we had that arctic blast (I'm guessing because of "heat" from lying on top of the foundation wall, rather than because I was dripping them), but they definitely need better insulation...

Comment: Without the insulation in the way, the warm basement air will also rise up to the pipes to help from freezing.  If there is any way possible moving the pipes inside more away from the outside is highly recommended.  Most frozen pipes happen in/on the outside walls.  You want a lot of insulation between those pipes and the wall.

Comment: That's an interesting point @crip659. I'm going to have a plumber out here doing some re-pipe work, and it didn't occur to me to see about moving those pipes at the same time.

Comment: I mean, at this point is there any reason not to simply strip the rest of the drywall and start fresh?

Comment: @Huesmann the usual (e.g. time/money savings): then I need to rent a dumpster, tear out a lot of drywall, remove and ten re-attach all the shelving, etc...  It's a lot more work that way.